# What are the differences in using Axios vs jQuery for HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been a jQuery user since forever. But now I'm building my first API that uses JWT for authentication. This said, most tutorials I find online to consume this API with authentication headers use Axios to make these requests.

I am already using jQuery on the project, so, I would love to make simple jQuery ajax calls, but I'm not sure if there's any hard drawbacks to using it.

This would be my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  error : function(err) {
    console.log('Error!', err)
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Success!')
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.id_token);
  }
});
```

Send the Request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
  type: 'GET',
  // Fetch the stored token from localStorage and set in the header
  headers: {"Authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')}
});
```

After reading the Axios features, the last one is: *Client side support for protecting against XSRF* . Does jQuery ajax not support that? Would I have to do anything extra to make this protection? Is there anything else that makes it worth using another library like Axios instead of jQuery?

Comment: Axios is not working in IE.

Answer (score 9):

I do not see any explicit support for that in the jQuery `$.ajax` documentation. That being said, it is something you could do with the `beforeSend` setting. In the `beforeSend` you would modify the jqHXR to include your XSRF information.

@charlietfl mentioned you can also do this in global `ajaxSend()` so it is applied to all instances of `$.ajax()`

This is what `axios` is doing:

```
  // `xsrfCookieName` is the name of the cookie to use as a value for xsrf token
  xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', // default

  // `xsrfHeaderName` is the name of the http header that carries the xsrf token value
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', // default
```

If you are already using jQuery in your project, and you can handle the XSRF yourself, then use `$.ajax()`.

> "Is there anything else that makes it worth using another library like Axios instead of jQuery?"

I would say most definitely. A library dedicated to handling http decouples the process from your application framework or presentation library.

Comment: Can also do it in global `ajaxSend()` so it reflects in all uses of `$.ajax`

Answer (score 6):

Adding support for CSRF (XSRF) in jquery is as simple as adding the following lines to your page after jquery has loaded (with your token rendered in a meta tag on your page):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

I have found (in the past) that Axios is more trouble than it's worth. Simple procedures, like performing A GET request to request a resource listing, altering an item in the listing with a POST/PUT/DELETE request, and then re-requesting the listing (to synchronise the view) causes cached data to be served, meaning the view does not change.  This is just one example.

**Edit:** I'm curently working on a Vue.js project, and I remembered a few more reasons why I stuck with jquery over axios:

It's worth noting that if you use bootstrap or something similar, you already have jquery included, so why include a second library?

And finally, I use a simple script which converts any standard html form to an ajax submission form simply by adding a couple of classes, and a bootstrap-alert to display errors.  It's intended for use with laravel, and (optionally) Vue.js. It's really handy because it handles styling of the form components to tell the user what is happening.  For debugging server side errors you can just remove the "ajax-submit" class from the form and it will revert to standard form submission. The anciliary operations in the script are most simply implemented using jQuery.  I have [put it in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/mp035/d53026e80f743025e069473c2970f00c).  Hopefully someone will find it useful.

I would actually be very interested to see how difficult it is to create an equivalent script using Axios, and excluding jQuery

**Further Edit:**  I just had to remove Axios from yet another project.  It is a PWA app and Axios does not have an option to use the fetch API which is required for use with service workers.  [I created a gist to replace Axios with fetch here.](https://gist.github.com/mp035/ae833b68cb45f51dbac7a2520731d22a)  Maybe it will be of some use to someone.

Comment: With bootstrap 5 there's no more, "I should just use jquery because bootstrap uses it", and next year it will be worth using it because Microsoft will finally pull the plug on IE once and for all. Or rather, just use CSS Grid